# .htaccess rewriting old content links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress site I was developing in `http://domain/dev` and now it's ready and I moved it to `http://domain`. Problem is, there are still some `img` tags etc. that point to `http://domain/dev/wp-content/and-so-on`. How would I rewrite these? I already tried `RewriteRule ^/dev/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]`. Wouldn't work.

Comment: Did you put that rule at the top of the conditions, or below them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your rewrite rule: `RewriteRule ^/dev/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301]`

The leading slash `^/` is not present in the URI-path tested in the rewrite rule. Therefore, can't be in the regex either.

Try this in one .htaccess file at `domain/dev` directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [NC,L]
```

Since there is no WP install at `domain/dev` at this moment, that's the best place to put the .htaccess file with this code. You can delete everything else.

Answer (score 0):

It might be as simple as you lacking the line:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

...at the top of your .htaccess-file:

Comment: C'mon, it's a Wordpress site. That just does not happen.